# Could not resolve org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5:2.1.3.RELEASE

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I want to add thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity to my project.

But when i implementation it, it is error:

> Could not resolve org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5:2.1.3.RELEASE.

> Could not resolve com.nimbusds:oauth2-oidc-sdk:9.38.1.

My build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.12.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'ru.arisu'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-release'}

}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'


    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.3.1'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-client'
    implementation 'org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5:2.1.3.RELEASE'

}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thymeleaf Extras Security 5 is not compatible with Spring Security 6, you should be using [Thymeleaf Extras Security 6](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf.extras/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6).

Remember that you are using a SNAPSHOT version of Spring Boot: 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT, which means that it requires JDK 17 at minimum.

Comment: thanks for answer. but i changed it to thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6 and it have an error: Could not resolve org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6:3.1.0.M1

Comment: Try removing the version, Spring Boot already maps the version for you. Just specify `implementation 'org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6'`

Comment: yes, i do it. it is the same error. maybe it's worth changing the spring version?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do by using snapshots, but `2.7.2` is the latest Spring Boot GA release. Snapshots version are not stable and may change a lot.